# Django - Import .txt file to populate data

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a Django web app with data on transactions between salespersons and customers. The source of the data is a .txt file and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to import all the data without manually adding them from the admin page.

I have a html template for a form that allows a file upload, but i can't seem to get the file through request.file

CSV-Upload.html

```
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@permission_required('admin.can_add_log_entry')
    def data_upload(request):
    template="CSV_upload.html"

if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, template)

txtfile = request.FILES['file']
stripped = (line.strip() for line in txtfile)
lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
with open('log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(lines)

for line in txtfile.readline():
    row = line.split(',')
    _, created = Transaction.objects.create(
        TrxnNo=row[0],
        DocRef=row[1],
        AcCrIsMinus1=row[2],
        CxNo=row[3],
        AcCurWTaxAmt=row[8],
        HomeWTaxAmt=row[9],
        ProjNo=row[10],
        LocNo=row[11],
        SalesNo=row[12],
    )
    _, created = Document.objects.update_or_create(
        DocRef=row[1],
        DocDate=row[0],
    )
    _, created = Customer.objects.update_or_create(
        CxNo=row[3],
        CxName=row[4],
        Postal=row[5],
        CxContact=row[6],
        AcCur=row[7]
    )
    _, created = Project.objects.update_or_create(
        ProjNo=row[10],
    )
    _, created = Location.objects.update_or_create(
        LocNo=row[11],
    )
    _, created = SalesPerson.objects.update_or_create(
        SalesNo=row[12],
        SalesName=row[13],
        SalesContact=row[14]
    )
context = {}
return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: what exact error you get?

Answer (score 0):

im not an expert but i think that your structure its pretty weird your view should be something like this.

```
def data_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from = Yourform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
           your_file = request.FILES['file']
           # do your things with the file
           return HttpResponse("it worked") 
    else:
        form = YourForm()
    return render(request,'template.html', {'form': form})
```

the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/)  also say

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method
>   was POST and the  that posted the request has the attribute
>   enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

Comment: Hi! I actually got this code from a tutorial on youtube, and it seemed to work well for his case but for mine the request.file command didn't seem to work. In this case, do i need to create a form in forms.py?

Comment: i eddited my answer, from my understanding you dont need a form in forms.py but you need to add a few things in your template to make it work

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear from your question, but are you finding that `log.csv` is being written, but transactions, documents and customers aren't being created? If so, I think it's because you're iterating through `txtfile` twice.

You read through the entire file here:

```
stripped = (line.strip() for line in txtfile)
```

`txtfile` has an internal position which is where you're up to in the file. After iterating through all of the lines in the file, the position is at the end of the file. So when you try to go through the file again…

```
for line in txtfile.readline():
```

…you're already at the end of the file, so `readline` doesn't have any more lines to give.

You can set the position back to the start of the file with `txtile.seek(0)`.

This is documented at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

FWIW, you might want to take a look at [Python's built-in CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) which might make what you're trying to do a bit easier.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusion, I added the part on log.csv to test if the .txt file was imported successfully. The code is supposed to be something like: "txtfile =request.FILES['file']" and then straight to "for line in txtfile.readline():" I realised there's no file being captured in request.file as the output csv was empty